# Solving Simultaneous Equations and Integrals with Python

Tags: python, math, equation, simultaneous

I'm trying to solve these simultaneous equations:

(1) [image]

(2) [image]

I think the answer is:

```
a = 0.0031
b = 0.6587
```

I tried:

```
from sympy import Eq, solve
from sympy.abc import a,b
from scipy.integrate import quad

def integrand(theta):
    return 105*theta**2*(1-theta)**4

def integrate(a,b):
    return quad(integrand, a, b)[0]

sol = solve([ Eq(a*(1-a)**5, b*(1-b)**5),
              Eq(integrate(a,b), 0.95) ])

print(sol)
print({ s:sol[s].evalf() for s in sol })
```

But I got:

```
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

I would prefer for the computer to do the integration automatically please, however I tried integrating manually:

```
sol = solve([ Eq(a*(1-a)**5 - b*(1-b)**5),
              Eq(  b**3/3 -b**4 +6*b**5/5 -2*b**6/3 +b**7/7
                 -(a**3/3 -a**4 +6*a**5/5 -2*a**6/3 +a**7/7)
                 -0.95/105) ])

print(sol)
```

but I got:

```
[]
```

So I tried nsolve as you can set the starting points for the solver:

```
from sympy import Symbol, nsolve

a = Symbol('a')
b = Symbol('b')

f1 = a*(1-a)**5 - b*(1-b)**5
f2 = b**3/3 -b**4 +6*b**5/5 -2*b**6/3 +b**7/7 - (a**3/3 -a**4 +6*a**5/5 -2*a**6/3 +a**7/7) -0.95/105

Sol = nsolve((f1,f2), (a,b), (0.5,0.5))
print(Sol)
```

but I got:

```
ZeroDivisionError: matrix is numerically singular
```

I next tried giving the solver what I think are the correct answers (a0,b0) as starting points.

```
from sympy import Symbol, nsolve
from scipy.integrate import quad

a0 = 0.0031
b0 = 0.6587

a = Symbol('a')
b = Symbol('b')

f1 = a*(1-a)**5 - b*(1-b)**5
f2 = b**3/3 -b**4 +6*b**5/5 -2*b**6/3 +b**7/7 - (a**3/3 -a**4 +6*a**5/5 -2*a**6/3 +a**7/7) -0.95/105

Sol = nsolve((f1,f2), (a,b), (a0,b0))

a1 = Sol[0]
b1 = Sol[1]

print('a: ',a0,a1)
print('b: ',b0,b1)

def integrand(theta):
    return 105*theta**2*(1-theta)**4

def integrate(a,b):
    return quad(integrand, a, b)[0]

a,b=a0,b0
print(' ')
print('a,b=a0,b0')
print('a: ',a)
print('b: ',b)
print('a*(1-a)**5: ',a*(1-a)**5)
print('b*(1-b)**5: ',b*(1-b)**5)
I = integrate(a,b)
print('I: ',I)

a,b=a1,b1
print(' ')
print('a,b=a1,b1')
print('a: ',a)
print('b: ',b)
print('a*(1-a)**5: ',a*(1-a)**5)
print('b*(1-b)**5: ',b*(1-b)**5)
I = integrate(a,b)
print('I: ',I)
```

I got:

```
a:  0.00309652149716206
b:  0.658740229906034
a*(1-a)**5:  0.00304887526056235
b*(1-b)**5:  0.00304887526056235
I:  0.95
```

(a,b) satisfy equation 1 (they have `a*(1-a)**5 = b*(1-b)**5)` and equation 2 (I is 0.95). As I say, I would prefer for the computer to do the integration automatically please :)

Comment: You can make solving the equations easier by carrying out the integration beforehand. Since the integrand is a polynomial, that's easy. Keep in mind that solving the equations numerically will require having a starting point close enough to the solution, where "close enough" is not well-defined.

Comment: Thanks @Robert, I've tried manual integration, report above. How do I define the starting point please?

Comment: @R.Cox [First entry](https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=sympy%20solve%20numerical%20initial%20point) 

Comment: @Suuuehgi With all due respect, I don't know how helpful it is to direct someone to an undifferentiated list of results which are mostly not relevant. If you know something specifically relevant, why not say it.

Comment: @R.Cox Looks to me that you have set up the call to `nsolve` appropriately (although I didn't check it carefully), so that's good. About the initial point, there is really no theory for that. The methods I know (there might be others) are (1) try a lot of random points within constraints, if any, (2) try a regular grid of points, (3) solve a simpler version of the problem (exactly or approximately) by setting one or more parameters to 0 or 1 or something, and use that as a starting point for the full problem. Since there are just 2 parameters, a grid search is feasible.

Comment: Re: updated problem. It looks to me that the integral, which is the right-hand side of `f2 = ...`, isn't right. I get the same expression except I see `(b**7)/7` and `(a**7)/7` instead of `b**7` and `a**7`, respectively. I am working with Maxima (https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima) to compute the integral symbolically. I'm pretty sure Sympy can do that too, I just don't remember the syntax at the moment.